# $e^{i\theta}$ confusion

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation, fake-proofs

I learned the following 
$$
e^{ik2\pi}=1
$$ 
and I was wondering whether or not $k$ has to be an integer.

---

**Thought 1**:
Since
$e^{ik2\pi}=\cos(2k\pi)+i\sin(2k\pi)=1$, equating the real and imaginary parts we conclude that $k$ is an integer.

**Thought 2**: Since $e^{i2\pi}=1$, if we raise both sides to the power $k$ then we have $e^{ik2\pi}=1^k=1$ for *any* $k$. So $k$ does not have to be an integer.

I am more keen on Thought 1 but I would like to know what is wrong in Thought 2?

Comment: $(z^a)^b$ is not necessarily equal to $z^{ab}$ in the complex case.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1628759/, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1104808/, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2765789/

Comment: If k=1/2 then the output will be -1.

Comment: Related to the 2nd part: Another related post: [What is wrong with this fake proof $e^i = 1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/281528)